# boost::variant with string and bool doesn't match string in construction correctly

Tags: c++, boost, variant

In the example below:

```
boost::variant<double, std::string, bool> testString("this string");
std::string s1 = boost::get<std::string>(testString);
```

We will fail with a runtime exception:

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.

Upon investigation the `which` value of the variant:

```
std::cout << testString.which() << "\n";
```

It is value of `2` so it is clearly matching to the bool during construction. This is further confirmed by the fact that this works correctly:

```
boost::variant<double, std::string> testString("this string"); // bool is removed
```

**Why is boost variant matching the `"this string"` in construction to the `bool` instead of the string?**